# Select a range of cells and colour their background

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project where staff are red, ambered or greened depending on their performance. The results are copied to another worksheet which lists and compiles their results.

When the staff go on holiday I want to colour the background of the cells to grey.

I wanted to select a range of cells in a row and wanted a button that I could press that would automatically colour all of those cells' backgrounds to grey.

This is what I came up with currently

```
Sub Macro1()
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
    For Each cell In Selection
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0      
    End With
    Next cell End Sub
```

I was trying to loop through a range of cells and colour each one - but only the active cell colours.

Comment: If you have a selection, why don't you directly set cell color from the Home Ribbon?

Answer (score 2):

> So I wanted to select a range of cells in a row and wanted a button that I could press that would automatically colour all of those cells' backgrounds to grey.

If you want to just color the selected cells grey then this will be do what you want

```
Sub Sample()
    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 48
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Macro1()
    For Each cell In Selection
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0      
    End With
    Next cell End Sub
```

if you delete activecell.select it works aswell

Comment: Why do you need to loop through every cell when you can color all of them in one go?